# How to check the session on button click by upload a pic

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, session

i am using code-igniter  ,upload a pic then check the session

```
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] === true && $_SESSION['role'] === '3' && $_SESSION['role_des'] === 'customer')
```

the session is not set a popup message .

```
 <div class="upload_box">
    <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" class="upload_btn" /></div>
    <p class="upload_text">Upload JPEG or PDF File</p>
    <input name="Submit" type="button" value="submit"  class="submit_button"/>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand clearly what you want.

Comment: i am upload a pic and click the submit button ( the session check ) if user is login the pic upload else the popup message display. how i check the session in java script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you can't check session on Javascript because it is a Serverside function.

I don't know if you know about ajax but you should use it so you can check your session on serverside during submit, this is how you can do it.

from your javascript

```
$('.submit_button').on('click', function(){ 
var file_data = $('#upload').prop('files')[0]; 
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('file', file_data); 

$.ajax({ 
url: 'upload.php', // point to server-side PHP script 
dataType: 'text', 
cache: false, 
contentType: false,
processData: false, 
data: form_data, 
type: 'post', 
success: function(the_result){ 
   if(the_result == "false"){
       //show popup
    }else{
       //ok
    } 
} }); });
```

and from your upload.php

```
<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] === true && $_SESSION['role'] === '3' && $_SESSION['role_des'] === 'customer'){ 
  //continue uploading your file
  echo 'true'; 
}else{ 
  //do not upload
   echo 'false';
} 
?>
```

Comment: upload.php  is model

Comment: upload.php is your serverside where the upload process and session checking is happened.

Comment: I'm sorry. What exactly is your problem then with the codeigniter? Did you try my answer?

Comment: the upload.php file write as a function and i call that function name